# How to set auto growth in SQL Server 2016?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

How can I set the Auto growth values in SQL Server 2016? The usual place in the database `Properties -> Files` is not available.

[image]

Comment: Be very careful when considering autogrowth setting, if you size  your database too small and you have too many autogrowth events it will kill your performance.

Comment: It is a Development box, so that should be fine. I am trying to change it on a production backup, and it was deactivated there with larger initial size

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

I see the option on my UI? but I had to scroll, failing that have you tried running the TSQL

```
USE [master]
GO
ALTER DATABASE [YOURDB] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'TheFile', FILEGROWTH = 10240KB )
GO
```

Comment: The TSQL helps,... Nothing in the UI...

Answer (score 1):

The key for me was in the missed 'but I had to scroll' part. I didn't notice that there was a scrollbar at the bottom of the list at first, but when I went back and looked it was there and I was able to set it using the GUI.